# Select some value knowing column name

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a table for example with fields(a:int,b:int,c:int,d:int)
I am writing a store procedure. This store procedure will give a string('a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd') and should give back sum on that column.
I am using SQL server 2005.

Comment: I know that I can use column_name and then use it with exec, but exec will open another connection. I don't want to open another connection.

Comment: I don't know any other way. Why stored procedure and not to build directly the SQL code

Comment: When we write: select a,b from x---> a and b are some kind of special pointers. they are not simple strings. so there should be a way of finding those pointers.

Comment: Because it is a time consuming algorithm and I should write it as a store procedure.

Comment: It should be something about sys_objects table

Comment: Stored Procedures don't automatically provide improved performance.

Comment: You either need `CASE` (Niktr's answer), reform your data (Such as Damien's Entity-Atribute-Value answer), or dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redesign your database so that you're not trying to implement the same operations against multiple columns. Just because SQL tables resemble a spreadsheet, that doesn't mean you should treat it as such.

It sounds like you may have some form of attribute splitting going on - where you have multiple columns representing the same "type" of data, when you should have multiple rows, and an additional column to distinguish these values (e.g. rather than having twelve columns to represent "values" from each month of the year, you should have two columns, storing month and "value").

Comment: You are right. Redesigning seems the best way. Thanks for your comment. But think that this table is same as a form in a program. So it becomes to hard to handle that from. Anyway I think there is a way to reach data by only having column_name as a string in a parameter.

Comment: I seems the best answer. And I will mark it. But please lets to speak about it a little more.

Comment: Without using dynamic code (as you seem to dismiss), there's no way to do it. A single SQL statement will always produce result sets with the same "shape" - that is, they will always have the same columns, where "same" means that they will have the same name and type. Since we can't vary the columns selected (a simpler task than what you've asked for), we can't accomplish your requirement either.

Comment: SO we don't have anything like select @Column1 from data?

Comment: @Masoud - no, that syntax (as you're probably tried/found out) would select the value of `@Column1` as the value of an unnamed column in the result set.

Comment: It is not important. The more important thing is it doesn't work! :D for example declaring a parameter and set it and use it. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CASE expression to choose the appropriate column to summarize

```
SELECT SUM(
CASE @col -- the param of the stored procedure
WHEN 'a' THEN col_a 
WHEN 'b' THEN col_b 
WHEN 'c' THEN col_c 
ELSE col_d END) AS sum_of_column
FROM my_table
```

Alternative using dynamic SQL inside the procedure

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT SUM(' + @col +') FROM my_table'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I don't want to use case. Just imagine if there were 500 columns. It is not a systematic way.

Comment: What about the dynamic SQL alternative?

Comment: I know that I can use column_name and then use it with exec, but exec will open another connection. I don't want to open another connection

Comment: When we write: select a,b from x---> a and b are some kind of special pointers. they are not simple strings. so there should be a way of finding those pointers.

Comment: What do you mean Exec will open another connection?

Comment: EXEC will *NOT* open up another connection.  You can check this by testing the @@SPID.  You'll notice that it is the same inside and outside of whetever code the EXEC statement executes.